# how to rescale two-dimensional plot for printing

Tags: r

Here's my code:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000)
plot(x,y)
```

I just created two standard normal vectors of size 1,000 and plotted them in the xy-plane.

When I look at the GUI, the scatter looks "spherical" and the axes are scaled equivalently. Cool.

But when I print the image, the x-axis elongates, and so the scatter no longer is spherical but oval.

I don't want that. I want to print the scatter with axes of equivalent scale. Help a brother out?

Comment: platform?  R GUI? Likely saving to file as Elaine suggest solves the problem but giving that information is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What if you save to a file and print that, like:

pdf('myScatterPlot.pdf, height=6, width=6); plot(x, y); dev.off()

?